# Excel multi value counter

Tags: excel, counter

I couldn't find anything similar.

I have a pretty big excel table but I can't get what I need from it.

I have a column for example of names

```
John
Johnny
Arny
Arny
John
Johanatan
Jeremie
Brook
Arny
Johanatan
```

I want it to return or show me results like that

```
Johnny     1
Arny       3
John       1
Jeremie    1
Brook      1
Johanatan  2
```

Couldn't find an appropriate excel to result me with that.

Comment: You can use a pivot table for this.

Comment: Put "1" in column B on each row. Use `sumif()` to sum each name

Comment: Pivot table, didn't know about it, thank you so much. powerful tool.